# Does C# have int8 and uint8?

Tags: c#, primitive-types

I have four questions:

1. Does C# have `int8`
2. If so, how can I convert a `string` to `int8`?
3. Does C# have `uint8`
4. If that how can I convert a `string` to `uint8`?

Comment: By `int8` do you mean an 8-bit integer, or an 8-byte integer?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

> 1. Does C# have `int8`

Yes, it's called `sbyte`

> 2. If so, how can I convert a `string` to `int8`?

Call `sbyte.Parse` or `sbyte.TryParse`

> 3. Does C# have `uint8`

Yes, it's called `byte`

> 4. If that how can I convert a `string` to `uint8`?

Call `byte.Parse` or `byte.TryParse`

Answer (score 11):

I believe you can use `sbyte` for signed 8-bit integers, as follows:

```
sbyte sByte1 = 127;
```

You can also use `byte` for unsigned 8-bit integers, as follows:

```
byte myByte = 255;
```

Here are some links for `sbyte` and `byte`:

[General Integral type tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)
[sbyte documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx)
[byte documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the c# equivalent is known as sbyte
2. Convert.ToSByte( string )
3. Yes, the c# equivalent is known as byte
4. Convert.ToByte( string )

For more info on the equivalent data types, check out [a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm)