# SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar returns SByte instead of long for INT8 column

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've created table with column type INT8. When I try to execute select query using SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar(C#) it returns SByte instead of long.

Why?

Comment: Please re-read what you have typed... Actually int8 is a byte, when long is 64 bit...

Comment: According to sqlite docs INT8 is long. Digit 8 means bytes, not bits. Maybe answer is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337882/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlite-integer-data-types-like-int-integer-bigi)

Comment: Well nope. C# wise check [INT8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947147) here also check long on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table)...

Comment: You are absolutly right that in C# it's type System.SByte. But i want to know, if I execute query "ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN b INT8;", which column will be created. [SQLiteApi](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) does not give clear answer, is it 8 bytes or 8 bits. I have made little experiment. I inserted value '129' and tried to read it in different ways. The main magic is that SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar reads this value as '-127'(System.SByte) and SQLiteDataReader.GetLong reads the same field as '129'(System.Int64).

Comment: **Update**. Line from System.Data.SQLite.dll source: `new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INT8", DbType.SByte, false)`.

Comment: Please add a self answer if it solves the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of data type mapping in System.Data.SQLite.dll source:

```
new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INT8", DbType.SByte, false),
new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INT16", DbType.Int16, false),
new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INT32", DbType.Int32, false),
new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INT64", DbType.Int64, false),
new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("INTEGER", DbType.Int64, true)
```

According to source code INT8 is System.SByte.
In fact .Net API for SQLite allows to store INT64 values into INT8 field.
This value can be read in two ways:

1. SQLiteDataReader.GetInt64 reads value directly without losing data.
2. SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar intitialy gets field type, then reads
   value with specified cast. This operation can loose data.

In my test I've stored value '129' into INT8 field. Then I tried to read this value.

- SQLiteDataReader.GetInt64 returned '129' (System.Int64).
- SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar retured '-127' (System.SByte).