# Csharp equivalent of signed char const

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following line in C++

```
 signed char const ix((delta_x > 0) - (delta_x < 0));
```

I would be really glad,if someone can write the above line in CSharp.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947123/does-c-sharp-have-int8-and-uint8

Comment: I have tried that,but still I am getting some errors,could you provide the code

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Where are you going to use this? Do you really need an exact translation?

Comment: yes, I need an exact translation of this line in CSharp.

Comment: So what you need to do is show what you have done so far & explain exactly what is going wrong. Do you understand exactly what the code is doing in the first place - that might give a clue on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Without any context of what you are going to do with this code in C#, there's not a long we can do to help.

Comment: Learn to think like a programmer. Don't add as a comment that you still get errors. The exact error text should've been in your original question. Helping newbies isn't worth it. They ask bad questions, and then they normally don't give you credit when you coax the relevant information out of them and answer the issue.

Comment: @JonathanWood That's a touch harsh on many newbies I think. Many of them are more than willing to spend some effort getting the question right and following through with the site rules and etiquette.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code

```
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    bool c = a - b;
```

Leads to this error in C#:

```
 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'
```

Which totally makes sense. Subtraction of booleans is not intuitive.

Your term does work in C++, but it's still bad practice imho.

This is what you probably want in C#:

```
    bool a = delta_x > 0;
    bool b = delta_x < 0;
    sbyte c = (sbyte) ((a ? 1 : 0) - (b ? 1 : 0));
```

You should also you use a clearer expression in C++, implicit conversion at this point is not readable and easily understandable.

Comment: Rather than translate the code as it stands, it may be better to understand what the code is doing & rewrite appropriately so it is more understandable - e.g. sbyte ix = (sbyte)Math.Sign(delta_x);